# add multiple sources in account existant

Tags: php, symfony, contextio

how to add multiple sources in account existant .. for example I create account test@gmail.com but I have add source test@hotmail.com in this account ?, how I try this ... now when i get mail for account test@gmail.com and source test@hotmail.com .. that is to say to get emails for two this@gmail.com and test@hotmail.com

i try with this code :

```
        public function contextAction()
        {
            $contextio = new ContextIO('key', 'secret');
            $s = $contextio->addEmailAccount($this->getUser()->getidContext(),array('server' => 'imap.googlemail.com','username' =>'test@hotmail.com'));
            if($s === false) print_r($contextio->getLastResponse());
            print_r($s->getData());

        }
```

but I have this output:

```
ContextIOResponse Object
    (
        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [request] => 
                [response] => 
            )

        [rawResponseHeaders:protected] => 
        [rawRequestHeaders:protected] => 
        [rawResponse:protected] => {"success":false,"feedback_code":"An email account for this user already exists"}
        [decodedResponse:protected] => Array
            (
                [success] => 
                [feedback_code] => An email account for this user already exists
            )

        [httpCode:protected] => 500
        [contentType:protected] => application/json
        [hasError:protected] => 1
    )
```

Comment: any helpp pleaseee

Comment: What exactly is the question? What library are you using (link) ?

Comment: @nifr I use contextio library